# Rational or irrational sum and the integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, rationality-testing

I wanted to ask you is it possible to define that the number `n` is rational or irrational from analysis of integral form of function of series, for e. x. we have series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n^2}}$$
and we don't know that the sum is rational or irrational, (we assume that we don't know that is $\frac{π ^2}{6}$). But we can calculate the integral

$${\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\,dn=1}$$

Can we say something about sum, if it is rational or irrational without calculating it?

Comment: I don't understand your question (and have no idea about what is going on with the weird choice of tags), but rationality of a series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} f(n)$ and an integral $\int_1^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ are generally unrelated.

Comment: So, if they not related, how to check if the sum is rational or not?

Comment: The irrationality of the sum is a consequence of the fact that $\pi$ is not an algebraic number.

Comment: Yes, but it is assumed that we don't know the result of the sum.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia (which I deem trustworthy in this case), we can write the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Series_expansions) $\gamma$ as
$$
\gamma=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|G_n|}{n}
$$
where $G_n$ is the $n$th [Gregory coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients). The terms of the series are rational, but it's still unknown whether $\gamma$ is rational or irrational.

Another series expansion is
$$
\gamma=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)
$$
We could consider the integral
$$
\int_1^\infty\left(\frac{1}{x}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\,dx=2\log2-1
$$
(if my computation is correct). This is irrational, actually transcendental, but cannot give insight on the nature of $\gamma$.

Comment: It might be sound crazy but the result of your integral is $log4 - 1$ and the sum of "Alternating Euler-Mascheroni constant"  is $$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left((-1)^{n-1} (\frac{1}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=log\frac{4}{π}$$ It's similar.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. The integral proves the  sum converges by providing  a bound on the values of the increasing sequence of  partial sums. The fact that the bound is rational doesn't help trying to decide whether the sum is rational.

Comment: Something like Parseval's identity could help to decide?